# DNS interaction between Cname and A Name

Tags: dns, cname

I need to resolve a subdomain members.domain.com by CName record. Then everything else needs to resolve to an IP address via A Name.

However, the A Name seems to take precedence. It sends *.domain.com to the IP address. How can I set it to send (everything-except-members).domain.com to that IP address using the A Name, and then utilize the CNAme for members.domain.com?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "everything else". Do you mean that you want members.domain.com to be a CNAME and all other non-matching *.domain.com to be resolved with an A record? What service are you using for DNS?

Comment: I've read your question several times and I still can't figure out what it is that you're asking. For example, what do you mean by "at a CNAME record"? Do you mean you want it to be a CNAME record?

Comment: Nathan, yes, by everything else I mean all non-"members" *.domain.com should resolve with an A record. I'm not sure what a DNS service is. I am setting the Host Records via the Namecheap interface (the registrar).

Comment: David, I realize I might not have all the terminology exactly right, but if you can't make out the difference between "at a CNAme" and "be a CName" and make a good guess about what I'm trying to accomplish, then I'm not sure how better to explain for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your DNS Zone create a new CNAME record:

**Name/Host/Alias:** members 
**Record Type:** CNAME 
**Value/Answer/Destination:** direction of host to point (example.wordpress.com)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I've done. However it doesn't work, because the A Name record seems to take precedence, and directs @.domain.com to an IP address, without checking to see if it should take different action on members.domain.com

Comment: Use https://www.whatsmydns.net/ to check your domain names current DNS record information, type your members.domain.com, select CNAME, and check your CNAME record information has been propagated, it can take 48 hours.

Comment: It has propagated according to that tool. The CName is correct. However, entering the url does not send you to that Cname, because the wildcard AName takes precedence.

Comment: Accepting this as correct answer, because it turns out it was a propagation issue. I just happened to check it via whatsmydns.net at the moment that it started working. Thanks!